# Dynamically populate model fields in a view on dropdownlist selection in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, controller, dropdownlistfor

I have a view in ASP.NET MVC application, with a dropdownlist and other text fields. The dropdownlist is populated with file names from a specific directory. So, on selection of a specific file name from the dropdownlist, I want to populate other text fields with contents on the selected file. The reading of the file is already taken care of.

I'm struggling with filling in the text fields after file name selection from the dropdownlist.

How can I do this?

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
    @Html.DropDownList("cardProgram", null, "--Select--", new { @class = "form-control input-group-lg" })
</div>
```

Comment: use ajax to hit a controller action which would look up the data you need for the fields, put them in a model and return that model as json. the success function of the ajax call would look at the response from the server and assign values to html inputs

Comment: @SINETHEMBA PAULA Add your other text field to the question and then say what value you want bind to that input field on selection of the dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#FileDDL_ID").change(function () {
            var file = $('#FileDDL_ID option:selected').text();

            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("YourAction", "Controller")",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { filename: file }, //pass file as parameter to controller
                async: false,

                error: function () {
                },

                //assuming your data property is called fileDetail1
                success: function (data) {
                    if (Object.keys(data).length > 0) {
                        $('#fileDetailtxtBox1').val(data[0].fileDetail1);                          
                        $('#fileDetailtxtBox2').val(data[0].fileDetail2);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult YourAction(string filename)
{
   using (var db = new DataContext())
   {
      //use filename as condition
      var details = db.YourDbset.Condition.ToList();
      return Json(details, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
}
```

Hope this is clear, I have tried to name variables as per your question. So basically, you are passing the selected value from the dropdown to the Controller action and getting back related data and populating fields with jQuery Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working. See below :
html code:

```html
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.cardProgram, new { @class = "col-lg-2" })
<div class="col-lg-4">
     @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.cardProgram, null, "--Select Card Profile--", new
                           {
                               @class = "col-lg-4 form-control input-group-lg",
                               @onchange = "BindProfile()"

                           })
</div>
```

ajax code:

```
    <script>
        function BindProfile() {
            var selectedProfile = $('#cardProgram').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/CardCreation/BindProfile',
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "JSON",
                data: { cardProgram: selectedProfile },
                success: function (profile) {
                    $("#sBin").val(profile.card.bin)
                    $("#IsChip").val(profile.card.chip)

                    $("#IsBatches").val(profile.output.splitBatches)
                    $("#BatchSize").val(profile.output.batchSize)
                    $("#SplitPostcard").val(profile.output.splitPostcardFile)

                    $("#SubCat").val(profile.batchDetails.subcategory)
                    $("#UserCodeIncrement").val(profile.batchDetails.usercodeIncrement)
                    $("#ExpiryDate").val(profile.batchDetails.expiryWindowMM)

                    $("#Bureau").val(profile.chipDetails.bureau)
                    $("#BatchType").val(profile.chipDetails.batchType)
                    $("#EffectiveDate").val(profile.chipDetails.effectiveDateOffsetMM)

                    $("#ServiceCode").val(profile.emvApplications[0].serviceRestrictionCode)



                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Controller code:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> BindProfile(string cardProgram)
        {
            var profile = new Profile();
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:59066/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                ViewBag.country = "";
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress + "api/CardCreation/GetSelectedCardProfile?selectedProfile=" + cardProgram);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    //profile = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Profile>().Result;
                    profile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Profile>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                    return Json(profile, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
                else
                {
                    return Json(profile, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); ;
                }
            }
        }
```